# Timestamp syncing errors on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, synchronization

I'm using the following code on google sheets:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",(LAMBDA(x,x)(NOW())))
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",(LAMBDA(x,x)(NOW())))
=IF(ISBLANK(B4),"",(LAMBDA(x,x)(NOW())))
```

The idea is that when an ID number is put into column B, column A automatically updates with the current time.

What I've noticed is that this code works fine on the computer that is gathering the data, but when I look at the data from a different computer, the timestamps keep being overwritten to be the same time. For example, today over 70 timestamps (but not all) look overwritten on my computer to be 8:59:41, but on the original computer the times are completely different.

My computer's times look like this, while the original computer has none or one of the 8:59:41 times.
8:31:33 AM
8:31:41 AM
8:31:48 AM
8:32:01 AM
8:32:05 AM
8:32:08 AM
8:32:12 AM
8:59:41 AM
8:59:41 AM
8:59:41 AM
8:59:41 AM
8:59:41 AM
8:59:41 AM
8:59:41 AM

Is there any reason why these times are getting batched together? And why would it be showing up on one computer but not the other?

I've tried moving the lambda function over, but it appears to be a sync issue.

Comment: For a reliable *static* timestamp, I'd suggest go the script way...